# How to extract the name of a request file only from a request?

Tags: web-services, nginx, url

How to extract only the name of file from a request?

I have URLs like these:

```
my_domain.com/dir1/image1.png
my_domain.com/dir1/image143.jpg
my_domain.com/dir1/image167658.gif
# [etc, images]
```

And these sections:

```
location / {
  # [..........]
}

~ ^/dir1/.(jpg|png|gif) {
    set $my_file_name $1;
    # [...........]
}
```

1st issue: it won't trigger the 2nd section when I'm requesting one of the URLs mentioned above

If I change it to be:

```
  /dir1 {
      set $my_file_name $uri;
      # [...........]
  }
```

It'll trigger it, yes. However, in this case `$my_file_name` will contain the *whole* URL, whereas I need **only** the name of a file/image. For instance, `image143.jpg`

Question:

How should I change the section with `/dir1` such that 1) it'll match the URLs from above and similar ones, and 2) I'll be able to extract a requested file or image name from a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression with a capture.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/dir1/(?<filename>.*\.(jpg|png|gif))$ {

    # do something with the $filename variable

}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.